# Laravel 8 doesn't send an email notification when notifications are set to job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-notification, laravel-jobs

I am trying to send a notification via email. Everything is fine as long as I don't want to do it on the job.
When I add `implements ShouldQueue` to the notification class, the task fails with the error `Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address in C: \ Users \ (...) \ vendor \ swiftmailer \ swiftmailer \ lib \ classes \ Swift \ Transport \ AbstractSmtpTransport.php: 195`

Of course `env` is ok, config (mail.from.address) sees what you need, which is confirmed by normal mailing and notifications when I am not trying to use job.

DefaultNotify.php

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
        ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

I was tried add `->from('address@domain.com')`, that was fine without job.

Comment: Do you already run the queue worker?

Comment: yes, but .... I didn't restart on changes, that's why it didn't work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your smtp settings